# Do I need a Bluetooth Dongle on a RaspberryPI 3 B+ to control GPIO pins from iPhone or android devices?

Tags: gpio, bluetooth

I'm trying to use Bluetooth to control the GPIO pins on my Raspberry Pi 3 B+. I know that my pi has Bluetooth capabilities built into it, but all of the tutorials that I've found online have required a separate USB Bluetooth Dongle. Do I need a dongle to control GPIO over Bluetooth when Bluetooth is already built into the Pi itself?

Comment: you are probably looking at *old* tutorials - you don't need a separate dongle

Comment: @JaromandaX make it an answer

Comment: @Jaromanda Thank you I'll try doing my project without a dongle.